# Configure bugzilla to reopen parent bug(s) if blocker reopened?

Tags: bugzilla

I'd like to configure bugzilla to reopen parent bugs if a blocker is reopened.

This, to me, seems to mirror the option I see of preventing a parent from being resolved if a child is not yet resolved, but I don't see an option to accomplish it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such option.  [OP's request to add it](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=642466) was resolved as won't-fix with this comment:

> Hmmm, I suspect that that would be better as an extension, because only a few organizations are going to want it.

No mention in the bug of anyone stepping up to contribute such an extension, though.

Comment: Any idea if there is such an option 6 years later? :)

Comment: nope, request was resolved won't-fix; answer updated.